# Generic Getting parameters from ssrs Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

After long and frustrating google search I have come here in search for help. 
I'm making a fun little program that get feed a URL for a SSRS report and (if it is even possible) gets all the parameters names that the report accepts, so that the user can fill them in.  But I haven been successful in finding any information on how to get these parameters.

I know you can just use the GUI that the report spits out into the browser, but I need the names specifically.  Also the GUI is for the user, but the program is mean to function as a sort of Data fetcher for another program so no user interaction is supposed to happen.

To make this even more frustrating the reports I need are made by a 3rd party company so i don't have access to the code

Is this at all possible?  When I google all I get as a response is how to fill the parameters into the URL when I have them, not how to get them.

I hope some of you can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parameters report use the `ServerReport.GetParameters ()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.serverreport.getparameters.aspx)

> Returns report parameter properties for the report.

This method returns a `ReportParameterInfoCollection` object

Try this code:

```
ReportParameterInfoCollection parameters = ReportViewerViewReport.ServerReport.GetParameters();
foreach (ReportParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
{
    name = parameter.name;
}
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much, it works absolutely perfect :D had to change the webbrowser control to a report control but that works amazing to.